Comparing two columns in two tables
I have two tables in access, with 2 columns in each. Column A and B in table 1. Column C and D in table 2.
I want to compare column A and C, and Column B and D.
I want the results to add a 5th column in the center with some type of match indicator such as:
A B indicator C D
And display the following results:

Where both A matches C, and B matches D.

Where one of the two matches (A to C) or (B to D)

Where neither A and B matches to C and D (respectively)


For #3, it would show blank fields since nothing matches.
Heres an example for 1, 2, and 3:

Apple Orange match Apple Orange
Apple Grape partial Apple Orange
Plum Kiwi none (blank) (blank)

Thanks in advance for any help!

SELECT Q1.A,
FORMAT(EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Q2
WHERE Q2.C = Q1.A),"Yes/No") AS Matched
FROM Q1;
Or:
SELECT Q1.A,
FORMAT(Q2.C IS NOT NULL,"Yes/No") AS Matched
FROM Q1 LEFT JOIN Q2
ON Q1.A = Q2.C;

Hmmm…maybe im not doing right as im a novice at this, but I get an error that there are characters after the sql statement. I split up the two statements and tried them separately, but then it doesn’t compare all 4 columns. Also, the query doesnt have Q1.B and Q2.D. Is this supposed to be included as well?

no. there are 2 similar queries as example, also, example compare only a and c colums. so be creative

there are a lot of resources https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+access+query+examples&client=opera&hs=tVK&sca_esv=32288416509471f0&ei=6oY9ZrHGI7uA5OMPpJaYqA0&oq=msaccess+queries&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEG1zYWNjZXNzIHF1ZXJpZXMqAggAMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMgoQABiwAxjWBBhHMg0QABiABBiwAxhDGIoFMg0QABiABBiwAxhDGIoFSPUOUABYAHABeACQAQCYAUSgAUSqAQExuAEDyAEAmAIBoAIHmAMA4gMFEgExIECIBgGQBgqSBwExoAftBg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

On which fields do you join the two tables? Do you have an id field, other than A, B, C and D?

its not a full answer. but it should give you cense of what you are looking for
next time provide data examples.
Table1



ID
A
B




1
Apple
Orange


2
Apple
Grape


3
Plum
Kiwi



Table2



ID
A
B




1
Apple
Orange


2
Apple
Orange



SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table2.C, Table2.D,
FORMAT(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.C = Table1.A),"Yes/No") AS Matched_AC,
FORMAT(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.D = Table1.B),"Yes/No") AS Matched_BD
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID;

result Would be



A
B
C
D
Matched_AC
Matched_BD




Apple
Orange
Apple
Orange
Yes
Yes


Apple
Grape
Apple
Orange
Yes
No


Plum
Kiwi


No
No



UPDATE:
i adjusted script - add additional column
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table2.C, Table2.D,
FORMAT(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.C = Table1.A),"Yes/No") AS Matched_AC,
FORMAT(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.D = Table1.B),"Yes/No") AS Matched_BD,

Switch(
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.C = Table1.A) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.D = Table1.B), 'MATCH',
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.C = Table1.A) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.D = Table1.B), 'PARTIAL',
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.C = Table1.A) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.D = Table1.B), 'NO MATCH'
) as COMPAREMATCH

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID;


It seems the queries should be tested with more sample records.

Use a Cartesian (multiplying) query:
SELECT 
    Fruit1.A, 
    Fruit1.B, 
    Fruit2.C, 
    Fruit2.D, 
    IIf([A]=[C] And [B]=[D], "Match", IIf([A]=[C] Or [B]=[D], "Partial", Null)) AS Matches
FROM 
    Fruit1, 
    Fruit2

Output:

With "blanks" and "None" included:
SELECT 
    Fruit1.A, 
    Fruit1.B, 
    Fruit2.C, 
    Fruit2.D, 
    IIf([A]=[C] And [B]=[D], "Match", IIf([A]=[C] Or [B]=[D], "Partial", "None")) AS Matches
FROM 
    Fruit1, 
    Fruit2

Output:


That will not work if any of the A, B, C, or Ds are null . or "blank", as described in the example.

@PhilippeGrondier: It seems so. See extended answer, please.

Shouldn't the tables INNER JOINed ? Because the cartesian query returns table1.recotdscount * table2.recordscount records for all possible combinations, but here a one-to-one relation is needed.

@ShahramAlemzadeh: Good question.  But that would leave out the no-matches or, at least, only list records of one table having no matches in the other.

What if more than 2 columns need to be compared? How should the IIF statement be written?

@Gustav, Thanks for clarification. About the JOIN ; I think an ID field should be present in both tables as the basis of comparison and this ID could be used for JOIN.
